# Named Colors in Cocoapod

Tags: ios, interface-builder, cocoapods

I have a catalog of color assets in a cocoapod to share a color palette between several apps. I am able to use the named colors in IB, but when I do that I get the following warning:

**WARNING: Unable to resolve the color named "Custom Light Gray" from any of the following bundles: org.xxxxxx.myApp, com.xxxxxx.myApp.**

My podspec includes the resources like so:

```
s.resources = ['UICommon/Classes/**/*.{xib}', 'UICommon/Classes/**/*.{xcassets}']
```

The xcassets item ensures that the color assets are included in the pod and does make them available in IB.

Basically, this is working but I'd like to resolve the warning in the console. Is this just a limitation of how IB works with resources in bundles other than main?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Seems related to this: https://devblog.xero.com/managing-ui-colours-with-ios-11-asset-catalogs-16500ba48205